# How are HYDRA jets flying without getting shot?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

S.H.I.E.L.D. jets fly in an unauthorized airspace using cloaking technology (which they (re-)developed in the beginning of *Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* season 2).

HYDRA doesn't seem to have cloaking technology. How are they flying in an country's airspace without getting shot?

Comment: Cloaking tech wasn't developed during Season 2.  SHIELD already had the tech (as we see in the Avengers movie on the heli-carrier).  What happened in season 2 is that they took a cloaking device salvaged from a Quinjet and made it work for the BUS, which did not have a cloak previously.

Comment: @BBlake Yes, that's what I meant. I never said that they developed that from scratch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

...They cloak their jets/aircraft.

> HYDRA doesn't seem to have cloaking technology.

Yes they do.  They're literally flying [the same cloakable Quinjets](http://screencapped.net/tv/shield/displayimage.php?album=67&pid=61337#top_display_media) as SHIELD, since that's where HYDRA got the jets from.

Comment: The jets which intercepted S.H.I.E.L.D. weren't Quin-jets.

Comment: @SachinShekhar Yes they were.

Comment: Prove it, then.

Comment: http://screencapped.net/tv/shield/displayimage.php?album=67&pid=61459#top_display_media

Comment: From above, they didn't look like Quin-jets.